# Removing duplicate db migrations from git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, heroku, migration

I'm trying to deploy a rails app to Heroku and I'm running into some basic git problems. I'm new to this all -- rails, git, heroku -- so I'm afraid I'm getting lost on what's probably a fairly basic concept.

I've pushed the app to Heroku, but when I'm migrating the db ($ heroku rake db:migrate), I keep getting the following error:

```
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateFavorites
```

Checking my github repository, and sure enough, there are two migrations:

```
20101007030431_create_favorites.rb
20101012173735_create_favorites.rb
```

The first file -- 20101007030431_create_favorites.rb -- does not exist in my local app, and yet it's still in the github repository after I commit. How can I remove this file and get my repository and local app in sync?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extra migration isn't in your local repository if you pull? What if you clone the repo again from scratch in a new directory, maybe it'll appear and you can delete it and commit?

Comment: Thanks, njorden. Considered that, but since I'm not sure how this was originally deleted, I was a little worried I'd just "half" delete it again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you type "git status" it should show the inconsistency. It will say something like this:

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    db/migrate/20101007030431_create_favorites.rb
```

So just follow the instructions there. To permanently remove it from the repository, type:

```
git rm db/migrate/20101007030431_create_favorites.rb
```

Comment: and then "git commit" and "git push" as normal

Comment: I swear, sometimes the simplest commands are the hardest to find in all the noise. This is exactly what I needed, thanks.