# "Multiple migrations have the name CreateLocations"

Tags: ruby, activerecord, migration, sinatra, rake

I am building a Ruby on Sinatra app using sqlite3 as the db + activerecord. I ran the rake task "rake db:create_migration NAME=create_locations" which created my migration. The only problem is that I now have TWO migrations with different timestamps and the same name. I can't seem to do any more rake tasks because of this. Not even a rake rollback:db VERSION=. I've tried going into the sqlite console and since I have not run the migrations, neither table exists. no rake db:migrate tasks work -- I get the same error: "Multiple migrations have the name CreateLocations".

No rake tasks work. There is no table since the migrations won't build the table via rake db:migrate.

How can I delete just one or both of the migrations from my Sinatra app? Help!

EDIT: Nevermind. I figured it out. I just changed the name of the class and the migration file name and that did it. I'll leave this here for people googling the same error. I had a difficult time finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017571/removing-duplicate-db-migrations-from-git-repository), in brief you could just delete one of the duplicated migration files.